# C# Windows Forms, painting combobox borders

Tags: c#, windows, forms, combobox

We need to show our disabled comboboxes as an image. The image has the same height as the standard combobox, but for some reason it cannot override the borders of the combobox.

Instead, it end up looking like this:

[image: 1]

We would like them look like this image, i.e. that the image is shown on top of everything - including the combobox borders:

[image: 2]

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what you are trying sounds really dirty - the best way would be, if your `ComboBox` would just look like your image as soon as you disable it!

If there is really no other way:

Create a `PictureBox` in front of your `ComboBox`. Set the image as the `PictureBox`'s image, make it `Visible` whenever you want to "disable" your `ComboBox`.

But again, using controls to simulate behaviour you would expect to be part of another control **is dirty**.

Comment: Genius. That helped a lot - and I agree, it's better this way.

Answer (score 0):

Get the location of you textbox, set it invisible, then  a the same location  place an imagebox